# JasperReports embed into Web Page

Tags: php, jasper-reports

Is there any way such that I can embed *JasprerReports* onto my web application so that I can work online from anywhere.

By embed I mean to use the s/w in the same manner as I used it like a desktop application.
I found a PHP client but I can't get what it does.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/php-client

Also are there any html to jrxml converter available commmercial, non commercial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JasperReports Server which is a stand-alone and embeddable reporting server : [JasperReports Server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server). You can use iReports to build your reports and then upload them into the server, or build them directly from the server with an ad-hoc view. 
The link you've provided does nothing more that connect with this server and use it within PHP applications.

Comment: Thnx for replying :) .Does this means that using Jasper server when I log on to mysite where I have embedded JasperReport Server I will see a screen in which I will be able to perform same things I can do in ireport or just be able to see reports.

Comment: You're welcome. First of all you will need to include the server ui into a jFrame for example to use it on you web-app. Second, it depends on the version you'll use. In fact, as far as i know the community version of JasperReports Server does not include the ad-hoc designer. So you can use it only as a repository and grant/revoke access to resources. While the commercial version does have the full features, so you can create reports within that frame (with a designer which is way more dynamic from that provided from iReport) including dashboards etc.

Comment: OK so in simple words if I use non-commercial ---> Use as repo. and see only previously generated reports. 
Commercial---> Whole iReport functionality and even more. on my website. This is what you meant right. Thnx

Comment: Yes, you've got it right. As far as i know the commercial version is still at that point (and don't think it will change), and iReports is a whole stand-alone desktop tool so it can't be embedded.

Comment: Does ireport provides any library which I can call or use to convert my json data to jrxml... basically I am building a web interface for that only.Now since Jasper is commercial if I can get something free I will go for it else JAPSER WINS :)

Comment: If you're saying you wish to use a JSON file to generate a report, then here there are some examples:
http://helicaltech.com/generating-jasper-reports-different-formats-using-json-file-data-source/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536995/create-jasper-report-pdf-form-from-json-object-or-json-string