# Display JSON Array in Table on Jasper Report

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a JasperReport using JSONDatasource that is passed by a JAVA function.

Here is my JSON that I am sending to jasper

```
{
  "Person": {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "Contacts": [
        {
            "Type": "Cell",
            "Number": "555-555-5555"
        },
        {
            "Type": "Home",
            "Number": "666-666-6666"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to display the phone numbers in a table. I can display the the other fields fine. But not sure how to display the table.

Here is how I am defining my Jasper fields

```
<field name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.FirstName"/>
    </field>
    <field name="LastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.LastName"/>
    </field>
    <field name="Contacts" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.Contacts"/>
</field>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the `JSON` language you can access the Contacts nested array only through the means of a `subDataset`, with which you can populate a Table component. Here is a complete sample(I have remove the generated styles to keep the sample compact):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="81afe112-ee1b-4443-8d1c-cb6d9ab95dd8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="stackoverflow/JSON_array_table/DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <subDataset name="ContactsSubdataset" uuid="4563e834-a9e5-43b5-9f0a-824948c73c73">
        <field name="Type" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Type"/>
        </field>
        <field name="Number" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Number"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.FirstName"/>
    </field>
    <field name="LastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="Person.LastName"/>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="300" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="d59811d6-a4e9-4871-a64b-f332d049e551"/>
                <text><![CDATA[First Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="80" height="30" uuid="ef25edff-1c33-4ec4-8dd1-21766039e6e3"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Last Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="80" height="30" uuid="e74bfa48-5040-4655-b419-f4f8e9f7e871"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Contacts:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="49d1558c-396f-4864-b71f-41b6c7d677c2"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FirstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="30" width="200" height="30" uuid="8ddaca45-a124-4c67-b2a8-50f7188097f9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="80" y="60" width="200" height="60" uuid="105c3994-b8a8-4085-81ef-4a0e55efc7c6"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="ContactsSubdataset" uuid="5459bdfb-6835-4007-8e56-566716c8c29c">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("Person.Contacts")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="b3d4c078-f65a-4213-9644-83b85b425703">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4b972b67-2f1a-4843-857e-c735dfc59c82"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Type]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="e618a748-3273-476d-95c5-4d232260bf0a"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Type}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="5b01cf7c-71bc-474a-9858-ef58479efcdc">
                        <jr:columnHeader height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="394f2626-8c49-491d-a09c-ef7f90132741"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="40ddb342-5be4-43bf-9fb2-a1fda76f53af"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Why this is so complicated :)) json is all about not being complicated , but this helped me thumbsup

Comment: @Narcis Which version of jaspersoft above example is working ... i try to use in 6.6.0 but its not working ..

Comment: Thanks! It's still working in the 6.12.1 version. I've created a JSON source file, added Data Adapter to this file (with the filling the report set) and changed the value of the Data Adapter name in the third line of the above example. I wasn't able to do this with the "query editor dialog" and don't know why this is so complicated...

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the contact data is in a json-array

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray contactsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("contacts");
JSONObject number = contactsArray.getJSONObject(1);
String numbers = number.getString("number");
```